# m3u8 hls stream to wav in one step with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line

I'm using to ffmpeg to extract 10" snippets in WAV audio from a m3u8 hls stream in two steps like this:

```
ffmpeg -i XXXX.m3u8 -t 10 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vn output.acc
ffmpeg -i output.acc output.wav
```

How can I do it in just one step to avoid the intermediate file and maybe speed the process?

I tried directly encoding the output with something like `-c:a pcm_s24le`, but this fails with a 'codec not supported by bitstream filter' error.

I also tried piping the output of the first command to the next like this:

```
ffmpeg -i XXX.m3u8 -t 10 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vn pipe: | ffmpeg  -i pipe: output.wav
```

and I get an 'pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input' error.

any indications of what am I doing wrong, or any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simply,

```
ffmpeg -i XXXX.m3u8 -t 10 output.wav
```